# Excel: Replacing Value Mid-Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

In the data sheet I'm working on, I want to calculate the Min, Max, and Average for each row and have the formula recognize the cells that have BDL as being = 1.35 without changing the value of the cell to 1.35. Is there a way to do such a thing? I'm pretty sure I've seen it done in the past. I believe I've seen a constant value added on to the end of functions.

Comment: Please share a screenshot or a public link to your excel file, similarly the formula you are using, all this will help to gain more attention to the people willing to help you.

Comment: @DavidLeal - please do *not* tell people to provide links and screenshots. 1) all material needs to be here, in the question, not on a separate site. 2) it's important to provide properly formatted text, code, data, errors, etc - not screenshots - many reasons listed here -> [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please edit your question to include all relevant details, including what you've tried, where you're stuck, input data, expected vs actual output, etc.

Comment: I've included an example of what I'm working with. I need the MIN, MAX and AVERAGE to recognize BDL as being = 1.35 without changing BDL.

Comment: You can use `NUMBERVALUE` together with `SUBSTITUTE` `=AVERAGE(NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(B8:F8,"BDL","1.35")))`. Note that this solution doesn't handle the ** which causes the #Value error. Probably solvable if you add some sort of `IFERROR` in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula should work:

`=AVERAGE(IFERROR(NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(B8:F8,"BDL","1.35")),""))`

(change B8:F8 to fit which columns you have your data in.)

Comment: Is there a way to make the average ignore **?

Comment: @ChristianPrieto Yes, the given formula ignore the ** as it replaces those occurences with #NA.

Comment: Actually I'd expect an `#N/A` in the `average` range to result in the `average` returning `#N/A`. Which would explain the OP's question. Replacing `NA()` with an empty string (`""`) should do the trick, ignoring those cells.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff Thanks, I changed my answer accordingly. For some strange reason my test yesterday worked (I didn't save the workbook, so can't see why, although I probably put the ** outside of the range B8:F8 which I used).

Comment: @tnavidi you were a lot of help, thank you for that. I tweaked the formula a bit. 
The formulas currently in use:

Comment: ```=IF(OR(ISERROR(MIN(IFERROR(NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE($B4:$N4,"BDL","1.35")),"")))=TRUE,MIN(IFERROR(NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE($B4:$N4,"BDL","1.35")),""))=0),"",MIN(IFERROR(NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE($B4:$N4,"BDL","1.35")),"")))```

Comment: ```=IF(OR(ISERROR(MAX(IFERROR(NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE($B4:$N4,"BDL","1.35")),"")))=TRUE,MAX(IFERROR(NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE($B4:$N4,"BDL","1.35")),""))=0),"",MAX(IFERROR(NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE($B4:$N4,"BDL","1.35")),"")))```

Comment: ```=IF(OR(ISERROR(AVERAGE(IFERROR(NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE($B4:$N4,"BDL","1.35")),"")))=TRUE,AVERAGE(IFERROR(NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE($B4:$N4,"BDL","1.35")),""))=0),"",AVERAGE(IFERROR(NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE($B4:$N4,"BDL","1.35")),"")))```

Comment: @MarkBalhoff you were correct in assuming such and I did just that.

Comment: @ChristianPrieto If you are on Office 2021 or 365 look at the LET function. It allows you to reuse a calculation result like a variable. `LET(ResultVal, Average(IFERROR(...)), IF(OR(ISERROR(ResultVal), ResultVal= 0), "", ResultVal))`

Comment: You are literally blowing my mind @MarkBalhoff !